# Java > Generate a lot of int

Tags: java, int

I searched for generating that, but its only 1 members , how to do this ?!

With `Random rand = new Random();` is that possible?
I want to generate a lot of `int` between 2 numbers,

But if you want to generate 1 - 100 numbers use :

```
for (int i = 1; i<=100; i++)
```

ex : `if 1-100` generate :

```
1
2
3
4 ...
```

Comment: use a for loop to determine how many times you want to generate the numbers using the Random object.

Comment: Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int- .

Comment: Sorry, but for now it looks like you may be asking for loops like `for (int i = 1; i<=100; i++){//do something with i}`. Please clarify your question using [edit] option.

Comment: so i is my number yes ?

Comment: `i` is variable accessible in `{...}` scope. At first it holds `1`, then after each iteration `i++` is executed which means it will be incremented, giving 2, then 3, and so on. Process will continue as long as `i<=100`. When this condition will not be true loop will end.

Comment: Place for answer is in answers section. Don't [edit] your question to put code/solution there, unless it is example of code which *doesn't* work for you. By clarify I meant posting more information which would allow us to be sure what you are looking for. Maybe some more examples with explanation what results you would expect and what results would be wrong.

Comment: its ok , you helped me ... Thanks man, but its my first post, idk to make solved ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8 streams, you can generate a stream of integers between two numbers using:

```
IntStream.range(lower, upper)...
```

If you want them to be randomised, then you can use:

```
Random random = new Random();
random.ints(count, lower, upper)...
```

You can then use methods such as `forEach`, `reduce` or `collect` to do something with the stream.

So, for example, `random.ints(1000, 1, 100).forEach(i -> doSomething(i))` will generate 1000 random numbers between 1 and 99 and call `doSomething` on each of them.

Comment: When i use system.out.println it not return the good result, but for (int i = 1; i<=100; i++) is ok , thanks

Comment: It is worth to mention that `upper` in `range(lower, upper)` is exclusive. If we want to include it we can use `rangeClosed`.